# How to remove a row based on all column values horizontally of the row in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data frame of:

```
a: 0, 0, 0
b: 0, 1, 0
c: 1, 1, 1
```

Where a, b, c, are row names in a Pandas Dataframe, how do you remove a row by a condition applied to all row values horizontally.

So for example, I would like to remove all rows where the total value of all horizontal elements is zero. In this case we would remove row a, and be left with rows b, and c, for the resulting dataframe.

Comment: `df[df.sum(1) != 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` with `axis=1`:

```
df[df.sum(axis=1) != 0]
```

Comment: Like this? `df.drop([df.sum(1)], axis=1)` why not this? `df.drop([df.sum(0)], axis=1)`

Comment: @AlanCA Edited my answer, don't need `drop` just the code I use

Comment: where do i use the axis?

Comment: @AlanCA Edited mine, just use the code I copied, and don't need to add anything else.

Comment: @AlanCA Does it work?